# How to access record's field values using lightning:recordEditForm?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have over ridden a standard EDIT button in classic app with a visualforce page and in that visualforce page I am calling a lightning component to update the record and it's child records. I want to access the parent record Id and a few more parent fields in this component's controller so that I can prepopulate some of the fields for child record,

how do I access the parent id and parent fields including other fields of that record being edited?

Screenshot : 
[image: Edit layout.]

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="dc" type="DocMan__c"/>
<force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" layoutType="FULL" targetFields ="{!v.dc}" recordUpdated="{!c.doInit}" />
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
<!-- PAGE HEADER -->
<lightning:layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header--object-home">
    <lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:scan_card" alternativeText="docman"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <div class="page-section page-header">
            <h1 class="slds-text-heading--label">DocMan Edit</h1>
            <!--<h2 class="slds-text-heading"></h2>-->
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<div class="container-fluid">    

    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
            <tbody>          
            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="docmanform" recordId="{!v.docmanId}" objectApiName="DocMan__c"
                              onsubmit="{!c.handleOnSubmit}" 
                              onsuccess="{!c.handleOnSuccess}" onload="{!c.handleOnload}"
                              >
                 <tr>
                            <td><lightning:layoutitem ><lightning:outputField aura:id="Name" fieldName="Name"/></lightning:layoutitem></td>
                            <div class="slds-m-left--xx-large"/>
                            <td><lightning:outputField  aura:id="contact" fieldName="Contact__c" value="{!v.dc.Contact__c}" ></lightning:outputField></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><lightning:layoutitem ><lightning:inputField aura:id="Ssn__c" fieldName="Ssn__c"/></lightning:layoutitem></td>
                            <div class="slds-m-left--xx-large"/>
                            <td><lightning:layoutitem ><lightning:inputField  fieldName="Type__c" /></lightning:layoutitem></td>
                        </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><lightning:layoutitem ><lightning:inputField fieldName="DocId__c" /></lightning:layoutitem></td>
                        <div class="slds-m-left--xx-large"/>
                        <td><lightning:layoutitem > <lightning:inputField  fieldName="Method__c"/></lightning:layoutitem></td>                                
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><lightning:inputField fieldName="TraceId__c" /></td>
                        <div class="slds-m-left--xx-large"/>
                        <td><lightning:layoutitem ><lightning:inputField fieldName="Received_Date__c"/></lightning:layoutitem></td>                                                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td><lightning:layoutitem><lightning:inputField fieldName="Status__c" aura:id="status" onchange="{!c.statusChange}" /></lightning:layoutitem></td> 
                    </tr>

                <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center" class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" type="text" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}"/>
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit" type="submit"/>
                     <div class="slds-m-top--xx-small"/>
                </lightning:layout>
                </lightning:recordEditForm>  
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="slds-m-top--xx-large"/>
    <!--NIGO EMAIL COMMUNICATION -->
    <div aura:id="bottomsection" class="slds-hide">
        <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
        <lightning:layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header--object-home">
            <lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:scan_card" alternativeText="primaryinfo"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
                <div class="page-section page-header">
                    <h1 class="slds-text-heading--label">NIGO Email Communication</h1>
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Primary Information</h2>
                </div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>

        <div class="slds-m-around--xx-small">
            <div class="slds-float_left slds-p-bottom_small">
                <h1 class="slds-page-header__title">Add Row 
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:add"  size="large" variant="bare" alternativeText="Add" onclick="{!c.handleAddrowClick}"/>
                </h1> 
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">        
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
                    <tbody>     
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.docList}" var="acc" indexVar="index">
                            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="docmancommunicationform" objectApiName="Docman_Communication__c" >  
                                <lightning:messages />
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8" aura:id="indexvalue" style="text-align: center;">
                                            <div class="slds-p-top_large"></div>
                                            <span>{!index + 1}</span>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8" id="{!index}">
                                           <span><lightning:inputField aura:id="select" fieldName="Select__c" value="{!acc.Select__c}" onchange="{!c.selectChange}"/></span>

                                        </div>
                                    <!--<div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8" aura:id="primarynamediv" >
                                            <span><lightning:inputField aura:id="primaryname" fieldName="PrimaryInformation__c" value="{!acc.PrimaryInformation__c}"/></span>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8" aura:id="dependentnamediv" >
                                            <span><lightning:inputfield aura:id="dependentname"  fieldName="Dependent__c" value="{!acc.Dependent__c}"/></span>
                                    </div>-->
                                         <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                    <div class="{!if(acc.Select__c == 'Primary' || acc.Select__c=='','slds_col slds-size_1-of-7','slds_col slds-size_1-of-7 slds-hide')}" aura:id="primarynamediv" >
                                        <span><lightning:inputField aura:id="primaryname" fieldName="PrimaryInformation__c" value="{!acc.PrimaryInformation__c}"/></span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                    <div class="{!(acc.Select__c == 'Dependent') ?'slds_col slds-size_1-of-7' : 'slds_col slds-size_1-of-7 slds-hide'}" aura:id="dependentnamediv" >
                                        <span><lightning:inputfield aura:id="dependentname" fieldName="Dependent__c" value="{!acc.Dependent__c}"/></span>
                                    </div>

                                        <!-- <td>
                                        <lightning:inputfield aura:id="dependentname" fieldName ="Dependent_Name__c" value="{!acc.Dependent_Name__c}"/>
                                        </td>-->
                                        <!--<td>
                                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Status__c" aura:id="communicationstatus" value="{!acc.Status__c}"></lightning:inputField>
                                        </td>-->
                                    <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8">
                                            <span><lightning:inputField fieldName="Rejected_Type__c" value="{!acc.Rejected_Type__c}"/></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8">
                                            <span><lightning:inputField  fieldName="Rejected_Reason__c" value="{!acc.Rejected_Reason__c}"/></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8">
                                           <span> <lightning:inputField fieldName="Deadline__c" value="{!acc.Deadline__c}"/></span>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="slds-p-right_small"></div>
                                        <div class="slds_col slds-size_1-of-8">
                                            <div class="slds-p-top_large"></div>
                                            <a onclick="{!c.removeRow}" data-record="{!index}">
                                            <span> <lightning:icon iconName="utility:delete" size="small" alternativeText="Delete"/></span>
                                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="slds-p-around_xx-small"></div>
                                </div>
                                   <!-- <td >
                                        <a onclick="{!c.removeRow}" data-record="{!index}">
                                            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:delete" size="small" alternativeText="Delete"/>
                                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>-->
                                <div class="slds-p-bottom_small"/>
                            </lightning:recordEditForm>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="slds-m-top--xx-large"/>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.Save}">Save</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.newContactError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.newContactError}</div>
</aura:if>
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this component inside a vf page in classic app so I got the contact Id in the vf page on load of the page from constructor of apex controller and then sent it to the component.

Vf page :

```
$Lightning.use("c:OneforceLightningOutApp", function() {
                        $Lightning.createComponent(
                            "c:DocManEdit",
                            {docmanId : tempValue,
                            contactid : contactid},
                            "theFormdiv",
                            function(cmp) {
                                console.log("Component created!");
                                console.log(cmp);
                            });
                    });
```

Inside the lightning component, I created an attribute and then in the helper method to add a new dynamic row, I simply assigned it to the field I wanted to while initializing the row.

helper :

```
addrow: function(component) {
     var docobj = component.get("v.docList");
       console.log('docobj'+JSON.stringify(docobj));
        var contactid = component.get("v.contactid");
        var rowItemList = component.get("v.docList");
        rowItemList.push({ 'sobjectType': 'Docman_Communication__c','Select__c':'','PrimaryInformation__c': contactid,'Email_Merge_Field__c':'','SMS_Merge_Field__c':'','DocMan__c':'','Dependent_Name__c':'','Rejected_Type__c': '','Rejected_Reason__c': '',
                           'Deadline__c':''});
        component.set("v.docList", rowItemList);

    }
```

I do not think it is the ideal way to do it but so far this seems the best approach considering the vf page and component I have. Thank you @sdandamud1 as always.